# What are the use-cases for local branches tracking other local branches?

Tags: git, version-control

In Git we can do this:

```
$ git checkout -b testbranch --track master
Branch testbranch set up to track local branch master.
Switched to a new branch 'testbranch'
```

What are the use-cases of such branches?

Comment: "Just because you can doesn't mean you should" :) I don't know the answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, there's no real reason you shouldn't do this. (It doesn't break anything per se.) It's more of a "Why? -- Because we can." thing as was probably automatically included in the tracking implementation in Git. It's probably just hard to come up with any sensical use-case :D

Comment: @NevikRehnel: that's exactly what I was trying to say :)

Comment: Note also (somewhat belatedly) that this is pretty much a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432345/in-git-local-branches-can-track-one-another-how-is-this-useful
Though, to preserve the answers and higher up-vote here, we might want to go and flag that one as a dup of this? @SergioTulentsev ?

Comment: @NevikRehnel: hm, thanks for noticing. Alas, the answers there don't appear to be useful, similarly to the ones here...

Comment: @EliBendersky: As we did point out, this isn't a very commonly used feature of git ;) and your question doesn't seem to be very high priority (in which case, it'd be more of a "how do I do this?" question instead of "what kinda things could i do with this?" :D )

Comment: This is probably the worst question I've seen here. It is absolutely generic in the wording, while you are looking for a very specific answer only pertinent to you, but do not specify ANYTHING in the question itself, just in your comments to the answers that while answering the question itself, are not helpful in your particular case. Spend more effort on the question next time, if you want more specific answer and spare yourself snide comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a local branch to track another local branch isn't generally useful, but I can think of a couple of cases where it could be handy:

- You may have some aliases or scripts that do stuff with upstream branches (e.g., via the `@{u}` shorthand; see `git help revisions`).  If so, configuring a local branch to track another local branch would allow you to test your aliases or scripts without affecting the remote repository or creating a temporary dummy repository.
- Suppose you are working on a new local branch named `foo` off of your local `master` branch (which tracks `origin/master`) but you aren't ready to publish `foo` to `origin` yet.  Or maybe you don't ever want to push to `origin` -- perhaps the commits added a bunch of obnoxious `printf()` calls you sprinkled in to help with debugging.  Anyway, whenever `master` is updated, you want to rebase `foo` onto `master`.  Normally you would just type `git rebase master`, but if you're like me you may find yourself frequently typing just `git rebase` out of habit.  If you do, you'll get this error message:

  ```
  $ git rebase
  There is no tracking information for the current branch.
  Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
  See git-rebase(1) for details

      git rebase <branch>

  If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

      git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> foo
  ```

  You may be tempted to do this:

  ```
  git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master foo
  ```

  but that can have devastating effects if you're in the habit of typing `git push` every few commits (you'll end up pushing your work-in-progress commits on your local `foo` branch to `origin`'s `master` branch, assuming you have `push.default` set to `upstream` like I do).

  Instead, you can configure the local `foo` branch to track your local `master` branch.  Now your habit of typing `git rebase` does what you want, and an absent-minded `git push` will only mess up your local `master` branch, not `origin`'s `master` branch.

  But it's usually not worthwhile to configure a local branch to track another local branch just for `git rebase`.  I think it's easier to live with remembering to type `git rebase master` instead of `git rebase`.  If I forget, I get an error message that jogs my memory and I try again.  No big deal.

Comment: Ah, finally an answer I can bring myself to upvote! Thanks, Richard.

Answer (score 0):

I try this command, and find master will perform as a 'really' remote branch.

In .git/config, the following was added:

```
[branch "testbranch"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

And you can pull from master using `$git pull`, and push to master using

`$git push . testbranch:master`

Or you can just type `$git push`, after adding the following configuration in .gitconfig

```
[push]
    default = upstream
```

Comment: What does it mean semantically to push from one branch to another? If I want to merge a branch into master, I `merge` (or `rebase`).

Comment: Maybe during git push, you can trigger hooks to do some check or anything other.  :-P